Change the positions of values in List 1 based on the values present in List 2
List 1: [CBZCYRUQ, CBDYBZQ, CBZDAEQM, CBZDAEUP, CBZDAEUO, CBZDAEUN, CBDYBZR, CBDYBZS, CBZDAEUL, CBZDAEUK]
List 2: [CBDYBZS, CBDYBZR, CBZDAEUL]
The expected output is: [CBZCYRUQ, CBDYBZQ, CBZDAEQM, CBZDAEUP, CBZDAEUO, CBZDAEUN, CBDYBZS, CBDYBZR, CBZDAEUL, CBZDAEUK]
In the expected output, the positions of CBDYBZS and CBDYBZR have been changed based on their positions in List 2. CBZDAEUL position remains same. Only the elements from List 2 should be interchanged in List 1

Here is one approach you can take.
List<String> list1 = List.of(
        "CBZCYRUQ", "CBDYBZQ", "CBZDAEQM", "CBZDAEUP", "CBZDAEUO", "CBZDAEUN", "CBDYBZR", "CBDYBZS", "CBZDAEUL", "CBZDAEUK"
);

List<String> list2 = List.of(
        "CBDYBZS", "CBDYBZR", "CBZDAEUL"
);

First, let us build an auxiliary data structure which will help reduce the runtime. This will act as a lookup table which will tell us if an element is present in the second list and the index at which it is present (in O(1)).
Map<String, Integer> list2ElementsToIndexMap = IntStream.range(0, list2.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(list2::get, Function.identity()));

Next, we will stream over the first list and filter the elements present in the second list and sort them based on their position in the second list. The Comparator Comparator.comparingInt(list2ElementsToIndexMap::get) does that.
List<String> list1ElementsSortedAccordingToList2 = list1.stream()
        .filter(list2ElementsToIndexMap::containsKey)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(list2ElementsToIndexMap::get))
        .toList();

For the final part, we create an Iterator out of the above list. We once again stream over list1 and check if the element is present in the second list (using list2ElementsToIndexMap).

If it is present in the second list, we use the next element from the above sorted list.
If it is not present in the second list, we use the element as it is.

Iterator<String> itr = list1ElementsSortedAccordingToList2.iterator();
List<String> sortedResult = list1.stream()
        .map(s -> list2ElementsToIndexMap.containsKey(s) ? itr.next() : s)
        .toList(); 
System.out.println(sortedResult);

